# R: transposing and aggregating columns

Tags: aggregate-functions, transpose

I have this dataframe with v1 as names of categories and v2 as items.
[image: inital data frame]
I need to aggregate v1 so fruit will appear only once, and all items in v2 will be transposed and placed in together in a single cell separated by comma.
[image: The final output]

Any assistance will be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do it using *transpose* in *aggregate* function.

> dt<-aggregate(v2~v1,data=dt,fun=t)

However you will have some unwanted text in the rolled up string which you can easily removed using *gsub* function

> dt$v2<-gsub("[c()]","",dt$v2))